# Constructors pattern

Tags: java, spring, constructor, telegram-bot, abstraction

For a good abstraction in a project with the Telegram Bot API, I want to pass the bot class to a Class with logic that execute the this.bot.
Instances of classes must be one, of course.
Can you tell me if this approach is correct? It may recursive exceptions be thrown?

BotService class:

```
private final MessageService messageService;

private final UserService userService;

public BotService(@Value("${token}") String token, UserService userService) {
        super(token);
        this.userService = userService;
        this.messageService = new MessageService(this, userService);//is good idea?
    }
```

MessageService class:

```
    private final BotService botServise;

    private final UserService userService;

    public MessageService(BotService botService, UserService userService) {
        this.botService = botService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }
```

The BotService creates a new MessageService and works with it, and the MessageService handles the logic and calls back to the same parent BotService.  MessageService use is only one method - botService.execute();
Is this pattern is good or do you have better ideas?

I tried Spring boot autowired, but when highload, the executes sequence of the program is violated.
And I don't want returns from MessageService to BotService. I want all the logic to be in the MessageService and just send  BotService.execute();

Answer (score 0):

Another idea could be using a Configuration.

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public BotService botService(@Value("${token}") String token, UserService userService){
       return new BotService(token, userService);
   }

   @Bean
   public MessageService messageService(BotService botService, UserService userService){
       MessageService messageService = new MessageService(userService);
       messageService.setBotService(botService);
       botService.setMessageService(messageService); // Maybe do that inside of messageService.setBotService(...)
       return messageService;
   }

}
```

Comment: It looks like just setters, but why use spring beans? I don't trust the application architecture for Spring because sometimes it caused non-obvious problems due to "class caching" if I'm not mistaken. I would like to know how it would be most competently without consequences to make the exchange of information between instances of classes and i think it's better to do it natively